# Get positive Button in DialogPreference

Tags: android, android-dialog, dialog-preference

Is there a way to get the positive button of a `DialogPreference` in any of its events?

I would like to disable it initially, and make it enabled once a `EditText` validates.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Simply call

```
 (AlertDialog)dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
```

If you are using a Dialog Builder though, make sure you call this after `builder.create()` and before `.show()`

You can then keep a reference to the dialog and enable the button once your conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. getDialog() is working in showDialog, which I override. Thanks for your help.

Comment: AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
Button ok = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
ok.setEnabled(false);

Comment: It worked only after BOTH `builder.create()` and `show()` method executed. Before `show()` return was null.

Comment: @corochann is correct, the button if null is you have show() after. Guykun's code is otherwise correct.

Comment: Is there any way to override showDialog with android.support.v7.preference.DialogPreference?